# Странное поведение подключенного шрифта при изменении font-weight

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Итак, я хочу подключить шрифт, чтобы использовать его разные версии через `font-weight`.

Одно название, несколько `font-weight`.
У меня есть файл с подключением шрифтов ***`fonts.css`***

Обратите внимание на

`SFUI-Display-Regular` и `SFUI-Display` с `font-weight: normal`.

Они должны вести себя одинаково, но при этом ведут себя по-разному.

Вот верстка, где я их тестирую:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SFUI-Display-Regular';
  src: url('sfuidisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('sfuidisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'SFUI-Display';
  src: url('sfuidisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('sfuidisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'SFUI-Display';
  src: url('sfuidisplay-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('sfuidisplay-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'SFUI-Display';
  src: url('sfuidisplay-thin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('sfuidisplay-thin-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: thin;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  background: green url(../../img/bgall-min.png) no-repeat;
  width: 1910px;
  letter-spacing: 0.085em;
  font-family: 'SFUI-Display';
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.normal {
  font-family: "SFUI-Display-Regular";
  font-weight: normal;
}

.not-normal {
  font-family: "SFUI-Display";
  font-weight: normal;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.thin {
  font-weight: thin;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">
  Regular-Regular
</div>

<div class="not-normal">
  Regular-Thin
</div>

<div class="bold">
  Bold
</div>

<div class="thin">
  Thin
</div>
```

При этом вывод у меня такой:

[image: Проблема здесь]

Что не так, я не пойму? 
Если что, вот [ссылка на Github](https://github.com/VictorGorban/Css-Fonts-Strange), можете протестировать

Comment: А почему ты считаешь, что они должны вести себя одинаково... Это два разных шрифта?

Comment: @Air, почему разных? Ссылки же на один и тот же файл, `sfuidisplay-regular-webfont.woff2`. В коде я просто скопировал `font-face` и изменил название. Я, наверное, чего-то в упор не вижу, покажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Вот на это я не обратил внимания. А зачем тебе два названия одного шрифта?

Comment: @Air, для теста

Comment: @Air, я попробовал использовать вместо thin число(100), и все работает. Почитал про font-weight, в css просто нет слова thin. Я думаю, в моем случае этот `thin` просто переопределял мой `normal`. Кинуть в ответ?

Comment: Я не знаю как пишутся шрифты, но чего то моя интуиция подсказывает, что в самом шрифте прописано название и менять его не надо... Хотя есть большой шанс, что я ошибаюсь...

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел проблему. В css просто нет такого слова `thin`. Теперь я использую только числа, типа 200 и 100, все работает как надо, причем 400 понимается как normal, 700 - как bold, все в порядке.

А запутался я из-за того, что моя IDE **подсвечивала** thin, хотя и не выдавала автодополнение.

Comment: МММмда...))))))